# There was an error compiling this function. Access 2013 Calculated field issue

Tags: ms-access

I have a table with a field which is of a calculated type and contains the following expression:

```
IIf(IsNull([OrderValue]),[TotalPhaseLabourCost]-[DefaultOrderValue],[TotalPhaseLabourCost]-[OrderValue])
```

For some reason when I go to open the table in any view it throws the error:

"There was an error compiling this function.
The Visual Basic module contains a syntax error.
Check the code, and then recompile it."

However, I have this database currently open on two laptops, one works fine and the other has this issue. I have checked both db's refs and they also match up.

Comment: Have you checked the Locale settings of both systems? Sometimes the arguments of a function must be separated with semicolons instead of commas.
`IIf(IsNull([OrderValue]);[TotalPhaseLabourCost]-[DefaultOrderValue];[TotalPhaseLabourCost]-[OrderValue])`

Comment: @Calaris: that's a nice clue, however I think that the separator is normally adjusted automatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a bit vague, so I can only make guesses.

1. Try to compile the code as the error message says.
2. check if you have any function with the same name as your field
3. Try replacing `IIf(IsNull([OrderValue]),` by `IIf([OrderValue] is Null,`

Comment: Thank you the third suggestion did the trick, but could you kindly explain why that would be causing this issue? Since it works on my other machine fine and they are both running the same version of Access. Would it be down to the different operating systems? (Windows 10 vs 7)

Comment: @Envertex:  Perhaps a library is missing on one machine, preventing compilation ?  My suggestion #3 bypassed VBA completely. Have a look here: http://allenbrowne.com/QueryPerfIssue.html

Comment: By libraries I assume you mean references? If so, they are identical on both machines. I will take a look at that link, thanks.

Comment: Furthermore would you advise I change the expression on the other machine too? So it bypasses the VBA as well

Comment: Changing the expression will provide a better performance, as explained in the link. And if you ever upgrade your back-end to SQL Server or similar engine, the perf difference between the 2 syntaxes will become huge.

Answer (score 0):

You probably miss the leading equal sign:

```
=IIf(IsNull([OrderValue]),[TotalPhaseLabourCost]-[DefaultOrderValue],[TotalPhaseLabourCost]-[OrderValue])
```

Or you could use:

```
=[TotalPhaseLabourCost]-Nz([OrderValue],[DefaultOrderValue])
```

Comment: I tried the equal sign to no avail, and the second suggestion does not work with or without the equal sign either. Thank you for your help though.

Answer (score 0):

For me there was some problem with some fields (it showed an error message `#NAME?` in some of the fields (date, number) in the 'new' record).
For me it worked to close the table, right-click it and open in design view.
For each of the fields with problems, I choose the data type (that was already shown) again from the drop down menu (so, same data type!).
Save.
Then it didn't give the error messages anymore.